# Adding and removing images with d3js

Tags: d3.js

*** problem solved please ignore ***

I'm trying to remove and add images with D3.js, and I cannot figure out how to add.  Grateful for an idea where I'm going wrong.  [Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geotheory/KAWQe/) and code below:

html

```
<h3>Click on the images - they should be replaced by new ones</h1>
<div id="image_gallery"> 
    <img class="image_gallery" src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/weather.png" width="200" height="300"/>
    <img class="image_gallery" src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/rejection.png" width="200" height="300"/>
</div>
```

javascript

```
var data = [
    ["http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/protocol.png", "http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/walmart.png"],
    ["http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/theft.png", "http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/questions_for_god.png"]
];
var image_gallery = d3.select("#image_gallery").on("mousedown", function () { transition();});
var index = 0;
function transition() {
    image_gallery.remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < data[index].length; i++) {
        image_gallery.append("img").attr("class", "image_gallery").attr("src", data[index][i])
            .attr("width", 200).attr("height", 300);
    }
    index++;
    d3.select("body").append("h3").text("but they aren't");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK figured it out. `image_gallery.remove()` needs to be `image_gallery.selectAll("img").remove()`...